# Can I optionally create a new scope in a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I had the problem while re-using a directive, that some tags already had a second directive, creating a new scope with **new** or **{}**, and some had not.
When I tryed to create a new scope, angular throwed an error, if there was already a new scope, created by the second directive.

I wonder if I can create a scope optionally, somehow.

I also tryed to create a new scope and replace the current one with the new created scope either in the link functions or in the controller function with something like this:

```
scope = scope.$new();
```

but that was also not successful while using this scope in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `scope.$new(true)` or `scope.$new(false)` depending on whether you want a new isolate scope or a new inherited scope?  Not sure you can call that without choosing true or false

Comment: Yes, I did. If you look in the API:
scope.$new() means to create a scope, which prototypicalls inherits from his parent. True as parameter would create a new isolated scope.

Comment: Do you have or can you make a plunker?

Comment: Here is one: http://plnkr.co/edit/HmKFR0kK0UjgVvY7bfxL?p=preview - if you see, the new scope is not used to compile the original template, but If I use the compile service after exchanging the scope, it works. And that's clear to me, because the directive compile function is executed before the linking function. But the compile function does not have scope inside, to manipulate it, as far as I know. - Therefore I ask for a way to change the scope somehow, without the need to create the element in the Linking function and compile it.

Comment: It would be cool, if angular would accept a scope : true or scope : {} optionally, if there is no other directive requiring a new scope, but ignore it, if there is already a new scope created. That would make it easier to re-use a directive.